# Use a different CSS file for within a DIV?

Tags: css, html

I have a website with a corresponding CSS file that defines all its styles. However, there is a specific DIV container on one of the webpages that I would like the styles to be different.

Here is my newbie question: Is there a way to specify another CSS file that applies to just within that DIV??? If so, how? If not, are there any other way of achieving a similar effect?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it in the following way :
 1. Assign a class to the concerned div like

```
<div class="different">
```

And then style this class different in your default css, for example :

```
.different{
    font-size:12px;
}
```

2.The other way is to use IDs , since ids are unique to one element and on page only one element can have that ID .

```
<div id="diff">
```

And than in your current css file  you can write something like :

```
#diff{
    font-size:12px;
}
```

They both will serve your purpose but classes can be used multiple time and IDs are unique to a given element. So it's up to you to decide which method you follow.

Answer (score 1):

You can write another class of your existing css file or create a new one(in case of new one, you need to add reference of it in your head tag and) and write their css properties for that div like this

```
.MyDivClass
{
// your properties here
}
```

and use it with your div like this

```
<div class="MyDivClass">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know. I will do it like this

```
<div id="special-div"></div>
```

and I will create a special css file and include `#special-div{/*styles here*/}`

It is best to include the stylesheet in the `<head>` I think.

Comment: creating another css file will increase the overall http request and its not advisable in his case since he only have to style one element .

Comment: Please note he wanted to use a different CSS file. And my answer is not only for a single element.

Comment: Friend he only wants to style one element , so providing him with the idea of different stylesheet is wrong.Thanks

Comment: Have to agree with Shail trying to reduce HTTP requests is a very important best practice. Even if they were two long CSS files it would still be a good idea to merge them into one.

Comment: Me too agree. But my answer for his question. I don't know whether he is going to do a special style up with an another special stylesheet or styling a single element. And I think he already knows how to use id and class to style an element already. :)